# Crystal Reports XI, formatted number always show currency symbol

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a crystal report designed using XI and used in a .NET windows application.  I have fields that use a custom format with the example of "(55,555.56)".  When the report is run, it always shows the currency symbol.

In the designer, format editor for that field, the only properties that are checked are "Thousands separator" and "Leading zero".  Everything else is NOT checked including "Enable currency symbol".

Why is the currency symbol being shown and how do I fix this?

Note: The database the report pulls the data from is a MS Access and the field type is Currency.

Comment: Use this: CDbl(currency number). Theres a good document on Crystal Conversions: http://ntssp.blogspot.co.nz/2011/02/converting-data-types-in-crystal-report_16.html

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I can't set comments as the answer though.

Comment: I have added it as the answer,please feel free to vote up. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: CDbl(currency number). 
Theres a good document on Crystal Conversions:
[Type Conversion chart](http://ntssp.blogspot.co.nz/2011/02/converting-data-types-in-crystal-report_16.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Go into the **Custom Style** menu of your field.
- Under Currency Symbol, choose **Disable Currency Symbol** and Fixed.